# Converting Date to string with DateTimePicker

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetimepicker, datetime-format

```
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM old where inputdate  BETWEEN '" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' AND '" + DateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString() + "';"
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        connection.Open()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "old_table")
        connection.Close()
```

I have 2 DateTimePickers of format Short. In SQL, the column name "inputdate" of DataType: date.
  When I choose dates with days <= 12, everything is working fine. When I choose dates with days > 12, I am having this error. I can see it's a matter of day and month but i'm still can't get the solution.
  Any help is really appreciated": Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: When you say it is working with days less than 12 do you mean no errors, or do you mean it correctly returns data in that range?. If SQL is using days for months then your result would not be a correct result.

Comment: I think you have a culture problem. SQL server is able to use the result of `ToShortDateString` but the culture is set to one that reverses months and days. Abdellah has good advice.

Comment: what do  you get when you run this query on your database? `select @@LANGUAGE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic solution is that you have to provide date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD date format into ms-sql query.

So, before passing date to query convert your date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @Jad - If the column in sql server is a Date then it makes no sense to pass in a string to the query.  Please see Abdellah's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I advice you to use the `Parameter` to use `SqlDbType.DateTime` and then pass the `DateTime` directly to the parameter (do not need to convert) , and also avoid `SQL` injections , like this :

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM old where inputdate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker3.Value
Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
connection.Open()
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "old_table")
connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

the output format of `ToShortDateString()` is not valid for sql server, and sql mixes the days with months.

try this

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM old where inputdate  BETWEEN '" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + DateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "';"
```

read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) more more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim dt1 as sring = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString()))

  Dim dt2 as sring = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString()))

Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM old where inputdate  BETWEEN '" + dt1 + "' AND '" + dt2 + "';"
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
```